# Show Date selected in Filter in separate text boxes

Tags: date, text

There is requirement to show Date range selected in seperate text boxes.
For example if i have a Select list filter for Dates and i have selected date range between 01/01/2019  and 12/01/2019, i also want to show this date range as text " Date Range selected by User is "01/01/2019" and "12/01/2019".
Let me know how to achieve this in Einstein Analytics

Comment: what work have you done so far, and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to get the Days between those two dates?

Via APEX you can use the `daysBetween` method:

```
Date date1 = Date.newInstance(2019, 1, 25);
Date date2 = Date.newInstance(2019, 1, 30);
String rangeDay = String.valueOf(date1.daysBetween(date2));
```

Via Javascript:

```
var date1 = new Date("1/25/2019");
var date2 = new Date("1/30/2019");
var rangeDay = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
```

Reference:
[Source 1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/126267/how-to-find-the-difference-between-two-dates)[Source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript)

Comment: The OP appears to be asking for a solution within Einstein Analytics